# java.io.IOException: Server returned HTTP response code: 403 for URL https://

Tags: java

I am trying to access the URL through browser there is no problem but then my program throws:
**java.io.IOException: Server returned HTTP response code: 403 for URL:**

Here URL is nothing but the attachment file path fro list item on my **Sharepoint Online** server.
I am trying to get the contents of that file.It gets opened from the browser but throws an exception from the code.

Code:

```
private String getAttachmentContent(String attachmentURL) throws IBSharePointException 
{
    InputStream is = null;

    try 
    {
        String fileName=attachmentURL.substring(attachmentURL.lastIndexOf("/")+1);
        String urlPath=attachmentURL.substring(0, attachmentURL.lastIndexOf("/")+1);
        fileName=URLEncoder.encode(fileName, "UTF-8");

        if(fileName.contains("+"))
            fileName=fileName.replace("+", "%20");          
        URL u=new URL(urlPath+fileName);    

        // Following Line Throws Exception : java.io.IOException: Server returned HTTP response code: 403 for URL:
        is = u.openStream();

        ByteArrayOutputStream bais = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
        byte[] byteChunk = new byte[4096];    
        int n;    
        while ( (n = is.read(byteChunk)) > 0 ) 
            { 
                bais.write(byteChunk, 0, n);                    
            }
    }catch(Exception e)
    {
        throw e;
    }
}
```

I have done all the settings in my code and even I tried all the possible solutions which are related to this topic but it still not working.

Comment: Showing us your code and what you've tried would help us better to understand your problem and consequently helping you out.

Comment: did you set user-agent header? some websites don't allow you to download from anything other than web browser

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally we found the solution and following is resolved problem.

Code:

```
private String getAttachmentContent(String attachmentURL) throws IBSharePointException {
    InputStream inputStream = null;
    URLConnection urlConnection = null;
    URL url = null;
    ByteArrayOutputStream byteOutputStream = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
    byte[] byteChunk = new byte[4096];
    int noOfBytes = 0;
    try {

        String fileName = attachmentURL.substring(attachmentURL.lastIndexOf("/") + 1);
        String urlPath = attachmentURL.substring(0, attachmentURL.lastIndexOf("/") + 1);
        fileName = URLEncoder.encode(fileName, "UTF-8");
        //This line is to fix bug # 966837
        if (fileName.contains("+"))
            fileName = fileName.replace("+", "%20");

        url = new URL(urlPath + fileName);
        urlConnection = url.openConnection();
        urlConnection.addRequestProperty("User-Agent", _Constants.DEFAULT_USER_AGENT_WINDOWS);
        // We need to set cookies as below.
        urlConnection.addRequestProperty("Cookie", _mSharePointSession.cookieNedToken);

        urlConnection.connect();

        inputStream = urlConnection.getInputStream();

        while ((noOfBytes = inputStream.read(byteChunk)) > 0) {
            byteOutputStream.write(byteChunk, 0, noOfBytes);
        }

        return new BASE64Encoder().encode(byteOutputStream.toByteArray());

    } catch (Exception e) {
        throw e;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

A 403 Forbidden response has the following documented meaning:

> *"The server understood the request, but is refusing to fulfill it. Authorization will not help and the request SHOULD NOT be repeated."*

You will need to contact the administrators of the server you are trying to talk to find out **why** the request forbidden.  It might be that they have not enabled https, or it could be a problem that is not connected with use of https at all.

Answer (score 0):

You are not allowed to access the URL/Resource. Check here http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/HTTP_403

Comment: Tried: u.openConnection(); and after that done u.openStream(); But still not working.